# How do I install curl with http3 support

Tags: curl

It seems like curl packed with ubuntu does not have http3 support. How do I enable http3 in curl?

Comment: Does this help? https://github.com/curl/curl/wiki/HTTP3

Answer (score 5):

I found it easiest to use the [ymuski/curl-http3](https://hub.docker.com/r/ymuski/curl-http3) docker image:

```bash
docker run --rm ymuski/curl-http3 curl --http3 https://example.org/
```

Note: Unlike other HTTP/3 clients, curl will not access the page using legacy HTTP first to find out its HTTP/3 location in the `Alt-Svc` header. This means that if HTTP/3 is listening on another host/port, you will have to use that host/port in the curl call.

Answer (score 2):

You will have to Build the experimental Version, It hasn't been released as a package.

```
 cd ..
 git clone https://github.com/curl/curl
 cd curl
 ./buildconf
 LDFLAGS="-Wl,-rpath,<somewhere1>/lib" ./configure --with-ssl=<somewhere1> --with-nghttp3=<somewhere2> --with-ngtcp2=<somewhere3>
 make
```

Answer (score 2):

I created a static cURL with HTTP/3 support for Linux with 12 architectures and macOS. You can take a look at it.
It is compiled by GitHub Actions.

https://github.com/stunnel/static-curl